# ajax and php send some stranges values

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to get some values from a checkboxes array and I receive this:

```
Array ( [0] => [object Object] [1] => [object Object] )
```

My checkboxes are from a php loop:

```
$vd[]="<input type='checkbox' class='vedere' name='vedere[]' value=".$result['den_vd']."> ".$result['den_vd']." &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

And my javascript is:

```
function add_apartament ()
{
    var vedere= $('#vedere input[type=checkbox]:checked').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "inc/ajax/add_apartament_action.php",
            data: { 
                    'vedere[]':vedere
            },
            success: function (msg) {

                $("#action").html(msg);
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
}
```

Now the question is: How can I get the values from checkboxes checked?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you print what you're getting in `var vedere;`? Means `console.log(vedere);`

Comment: [object Object][object Object][object Object]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
var vedere = $("#vedere input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
   return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

See **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x6uFU/)**.

Comment: Thanks! May be you could consider accepting the solution. :))